# How to view in julia surf plot?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

Using the command in julia `surf(x,y,z)`, how to control the view? I am using PyPlot.

[This example](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/a-torus/) indicates I should try `view_init(a,b)`, but that does not work.

I have a couple different versions of julia installed :  0.4.3 and 0.7. Suggestions for either are welcomed.

Comment: This is a Python question. Julia is different programming language.I edited your question tag. You might also consider using matplotlib tags.

Comment: I  am converting the code to Julia. I am using PyPlot

Comment: I highly recommend using Julia 1.0 or 1.1.  0.4.3 is ancient history.

Comment: agreed!  since i do scicomp type work, mostly for publications which once they are done they are done, some old projects will always remain in old versions.  new versions must wait for new projects.  the update process is def. a work in progress ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah hah.  Here we go.  The answer is:

```
figure();
ax = gca(projection="3d");
surf(x,y,z);
ax[:view_init](30,26);
```